# Android C# Clear TextView before populating with new data

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I'm trying to clear 3 TextView fields before new data is then displayed. I'm using SQLite and returning 3 phone numbers.

I can't run the app as I get "**cannot convert from string to int**" on the

```
txtFire.SetText("");
```

section of code.

The 3 fields in my SQLite DB are TEXT fields, so slightly confused on how to resolve this.

Any advice is appreciated.

```
private void EmergencyServicesData()
    {
        var location = FindViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(Resource.Id.autoCompleteCountry).Text;
            ICursor selectData = sqliteDB.RawQuery("SELECT POLICE, FIRE, MEDICAL FROM EmergencyServices WHERE COUNTRY = '" + location + "'", new string[] { });
            if (selectData.Count > 0)
            {
                selectData.MoveToFirst();
                do
                {
                txtFire = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtFire);
                txtMedical = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtMedical);
                txtPolice = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtPolice);

                txtFire.SetText("");
                txtMedical.SetText("");
                txtPolice.SetText("");


                EmergencyServices emergencyServices = new EmergencyServices();

                    EmergencyServices.Clear();
                    emergencyServices.POLICE = selectData.GetString(selectData.GetColumnIndex("POLICE"));
                    emergencyServices.FIRE = selectData.GetString(selectData.GetColumnIndex("FIRE"));
                    emergencyServices.MEDICAL = selectData.GetString(selectData.GetColumnIndex("MEDICAL"));
                    EmergencyServices.Add(emergencyServices);

            }
                while (selectData.MoveToNext());
                selectData.Close();
            }
            foreach (var item in EmergencyServices)
            {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)BaseContext.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
                View addView = layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.EmergencyServices, null);
                TextView txtPoliceData = addView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtPolice);
                TextView txtFireData = addView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtFire);
                TextView txtMedicalData = addView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtMedical);
                txtPoliceData.Text = item.POLICE;
                txtFireData.Text = item.FIRE;
                txtMedicalData.Text = item.MEDICAL;
                container.AddView(addView);
            }
    }
```

Comment: is this Xamarin framework?

Comment: @flopshot I'm using a blank Xamarin.android project

Comment: I've tried using `txtFire.Text = "";` but I get System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @TwistedSteel why are you connecting `TextView` with `ids` in loop? And check this line: `txtFire = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtFire);` - do you have id `txtFire` in layout

Comment: @Yupi Yes I have the txtFire etc in the Layout. Not sure why I put it in the loop. It can go in the button click really I suppose.

Comment: If this line `txtFire.Text = "";` throws `NullPointerException` than surely `txtFire` is `null`

Comment: These `FindViewById` are going to be null Pointers in`do{}`, because they need to call the `FindViewById` of the parent container, like `addview.FindViewById` in your foeach,but  I dont know why you put `FindViewById` in the `foreach` loop

Answer (score 0):

You have nullpointers in your textviews. Change to this.

```
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)BaseContext.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
    View addView = layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.EmergencyServices, null);
    txtFire = addView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtFire);
    txtMedical = addView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtMedical);
    txtPolice = addView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtPolice);
```